# Whether Adding a new matching service in temporal workflow will cause all cache queue outdated

Tags: temporal-workflow

Matching service use consistent hash decide which queue is assigned to which server.
Most of time, the server will poll task from cache instead of persistent database.

If I add a new matching service, All cache in queue will be re-consistent-hash to new places, and this will cause all old cache outdated. Will it cause any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time tasks are not cached but matched immediately to a waiting long poll. We call it a sync match. So adding a matching service shouldn't affect the health of the running applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For waiting long poll, If worker is blocked by one empty partition queue until a task is coming, who will consume tasks in other partitions? If we have three partitions and only one worker. The worker is blocked for partition 1.  It need to wait a task arrived to partition 1, even if partition 2 and partition 3 has already a lot of tasks?

Comment: The poll and add-task requests are forwarded to a parent partition. So the matching is going to happen. Also even a single worker uses multiple parallel poll threads.